# How can a file be generated in a browser

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular2 seems to be generating files on the fly in a browser. For example, if I check `sources` I can see the following files created:

[image]

I'm wondering how it's possible to generate these files so that they appear in `(no domain)` section? I've checked the `index.html` in a browser and I don't see `script` tags with these files.

Comment: they are transpiled files ..! your .ts files converted to .js files.! You do not see those included probably because of your configurations .
i.e there would be just 1 JS File included which will contain all this code.

Comment: I don't have `ts` files like these. And these are definitely generated by angular compiler in a browser (JIT compilation)

Comment: You must have HelloWorldComponent, AppComponent which are exported in classes.

when u transpile those this files are generated irrespective of whether u select JIT or AOT compiler.

Comment: Sure I have those, but the transpiled files content is very different from that of `component.ngfactory.js` files. And both transpiled and generated files are available in the sources

Comment: These files come from the "Ahead-Of-Time" compilation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: both are included probably because of webpack confuguration, tag related to rootDirs.. include that plz.

Comment: @mvermand, I don't use AOT, so these are generated on the fly (JIT)

Comment: @ParthGhiya, no, I don't use webpack and I don't see these files requested in network tab. They are definitely generated on the client side

Comment: what do u use for transpilation then ?
They are generated as a result of transpilation process for sure.! they is no request because they are generated on client side because of JIT...

Something like if u use sourcemaps:true in webpack, then you see typescript files & are able to debug typescript files

Comment: @ParthGhiya, I've figured that out. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42525801/2545680).

Comment: @mvermand, I've figured that out. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42525801/2545680).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular uses `new Function()` approach described [here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html) to generate new code. The implementation is available [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/output/output_jit.ts#L15):

```
function evalExpression(
    sourceUrl: string, ctx: EmitterVisitorContext, vars: {[key: string]: any}): any {
  const fnBody =
      `${ctx.toSource()}\n//# sourceURL=${sourceUrl}\n${ctx.toSourceMapGenerator().toJsComment()}`;
  const fnArgNames: string[] = [];
  const fnArgValues: any[] = [];
  for (const argName in vars) {
    fnArgNames.push(argName);
    fnArgValues.push(vars[argName]);
  }
  return new Function(...fnArgNames.concat(fnBody))(...fnArgValues);
}
```

Also, angular attaches the following text to the generated file:

```
//# sourceURL=/CommonModule/NgClass/wrapper.ngfactory.js
```

Which forces browser to show the generated content under `(no domain)` in `sources` under the specified URL. Here is the small snippet that demonstrates what angular compiler does:

```
var body = "function my(x, y) {return x+y}; return my; //# sourceURL=/MyCustomURLPath/wrapper.ngfactory.js"
var f = new Function(body)();
var result = f(3, 4);
```

Now, if you observe `sources`, you'll see the generated code under `/MyCustomURLPath/wrapper.ngfactory.js`